# Is it plagiarism for my thesis advisor to publish a paper using content from my thesis without citation?

Tags: publications, thesis, advisor, plagiarism

I did my master thesis last year and recently I found out that a group of four faculty members in my department, including my thesis advisor, have published an ACM paper based on that. (A publish subscribe system based on SDN)

I will be honest. The problem statement was put forward by the faculty. The implementation (design of algorithms and coding) was completely done by me in my thesis. Then they further extended it to a distributed SDN controller environment.

In the paper, an entire section is devoted to the algorithms and implementation. Where they have almost ripped off from my thesis. The sentence structures have been changed and some beautification done to the algorithms to make it look concise.

However, I have not been given any acknowledgement or citation. Anyone who'll read that paper will have an impression that the authors were the only brains behind the project.

The university holds the copyright of my thesis. So I am not sure if this qualifies for plagiarism. But certainly, I feel it is not fair to brush someone's contribution under the carpet.

What can I do about it ? Or am I mistaken and they have every right to do how they feel as I am no longer a student there and the copyright is with them ?

Comment: What do you mean, "the department has published a paper"? Departments don't publish papers, people do. Do you mean a student/faculty from your department published the paper? Was the student/faculty who authored the paper involved in any way with supervising your thesis?

Comment: Yes, the faculty published the paper, a group of four authors. And one of the authors was my supervisor.

Comment: if he/she was your supervisor then he have the right to extend that work and he/she is allowed to publish as he/she was a co-author (supervisor) in your theses.

Comment: @ZeshanKhanAlvi I am not against extension. But as per you supervisor = co-author ? Even if he is considered a co-author, he can leave out the other co-author (actually the author) i.e., me ?

Comment: i am not saying supervisor = co-author if he is the author in your publication then he would be the co-author.

Comment: have you published your research?

Comment: No. I wrote my master thesis, and they published a paper taking content from my thesis.

Comment: @gaganbm can you please share the result of your story?

Comment: @SalvadorDali No result yet. As most answers advice, I will contact the faculty and will get their side of story.

Comment: @gaganbm sorry for being vague. I meant can you post the result when you will get them. I do realize that it can take a lot of time to get them. I also think that you have to contact the journal, providing them with the copy of your theses (it is not enough to ask only your adviser what he thinks about his steps. Even if the person is wrong, not always he admits so)

Comment: Your supervisor is not automatically a co-author.

Comment: What does _"The university holds the copyright of my thesis"_ mean? They might have the right and even the exclusive to publishing/commercializing it, but I doubt even a pro-Corp system such as the US one, allows someone to completely foreit _credits_ to his own work... now does it?

Comment: If they do cite your thesis, this won't do you any good anyway. You need to have a published article. Publish an article, and in this article mention that your work has led to further publications --- and cite the paper in question. When your article will be reviewed, the journal reviewer will automatically have to investigate the issue. Once it gets published, then see if you still have a problem. Don't worry about "punishing" them. I actually had a "coauthor" who had to be included (a professor), who made the paper worse ;-) But I have other things to worry about.

Comment: _If they do cite your thesis, this won't do you any good anyway_ — [citation needed]  Prior work is prior work.

Comment: @o0'. The US legal system doesn't care at all about who gets or takes credit for work. That's an academic honesty issue, not a legal issue. If I want to hire a ghostwriter to write my "autobiography" and I can find an author willing to do it and take no credit, why should the law tell us both that we can't make a mutually-beneficial arrangement?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because it's not mutually beneficial.

Comment: @o0'. In my example, a person completely forfeits credit to their own work and it *is* mutually beneficial. You asked why a legal system would allow a person to completely forfeit credit to their own work and the obvious answer is that it would be stupid to prohibit such arrangements because they include a large number of mutually-beneficial arrangements. But in any event, the legal system generally doesn't care about who gets credit for a work so much as it cares about rights granted under copyright not being violated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz And I'm saying that it's stupid to allow forfeiting such rights, because it's better to always have credits for your work.

Comment: @o0'. The law should prohibit particular types of arrangements on the mere grounds that there are always superior possible arrangements is a terrible argument. It's also pretty obviously absurd to argue that forfeiting the right to credit in exchange for money or other consideration is never of value to the person forfeiting the credit.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Whether or not the department holds the copyright to your thesis is irrelevant. Using someone else's ideas without appropriate attribution is plagiarism, period.

So, if your advisor used *your* original, non-trivial scientific ideas (or your non-trivial description of those ideas) in his paper without attributing them to you, then he has committed misconduct.

The only thing that *may* be questionable is whether or not your original intellectual ideas were actually used in the paper. **What you describe definitely sounds pretty damning**, and the more information you add, the worse it sounds; but as strangers on the Internet, we don't have the whole story.

For example: Given that the idea for the thesis was the advisor's, and the paper describes a non-trivial extension, it's possible (though perhaps not likely, depending on the scope of the work) that your advisor was working on the extended version himself independently of your thesis.

It's also possible that he considers your work to be a straightforward implementation of his idea, and not an intellectual contribution - that is, he believes you were doing the work of a staff programmer, not a scientist or engineer. In which case, an acknowledgement would probably have been appropriate, but it's not necessarily plagiarism to omit it.

The degree to which your work constitutes an intellectual contribution to your advisor's paper is impossible for strangers on the Internet to judge.

I suggest you email your former thesis advisor, tell him you've seen the paper, and ask (in a non-confrontational way) how it relates to your thesis work. Then decide how to proceed from there.

Note that pursuing the matter beyond that (i.e. formally accusing him of plagiarism) may involve some serious negative consequences for you, so consider this carefully before proceeding. The morally just course of action may or may not actually be in your best interests.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Firstly, my ideas are *definitely* used in the paper. Even after leaving the University, I used to help them occasionally in their extension work. Second, the write-up of that particular section in the paper is just an english-to-english translation of my wordings. Third, it might or might not be trivial, that's kind of subjective. Anyways, I will try to contact them. Thanks.

Comment: @gaganbm yes, it *does* sound pretty bad. But as a stranger on the Internet, I'm not prepared to judge definitively. You're in a much better position to judge than we are. I suggest you email him and see what he says. If he did use your non-trivial ideas then yes, it *absolutely* is plagiarism.

Comment: @ff524: Even disregarding non-trivial ideas, if sentence structures line up etc. that would be plagiarism no matter how simplistic the ideas presented within. Additionally the serious negative consequences tend to apply to people still working in an academic environment. If he left the academic world for good I don't believe he should worry much about that.

Comment: @David that would be the "non-trivial description" I mentioned. I'm not in a position to judge the degree of overlap. And, even if he's not in the academic world, he may still want recommendation letters, etc from his former supervisor. Just something to think about.

Comment: "...  may involve some serious negative consequences for you, so consider this carefully" -- every time I read something like this (knowing that it's true) I get a little sick. That is on almost every "what should I do about misbehaviour X?". Tenured guys own everybody else's asses so they can get away with anything. Hiring faculty of moral integrity also seems optional these days.</rant>

Comment: _he believes you were doing the work of a staff programmer, not a scientist or engineer_ — If that were the case, the advisor shouldn't have signed off on the master's thesis.

Comment: Sorry but your first paragraph is not quite right. By definition, if entity A holds the copyright on work B, then the ideas within work B are entity A's by rights, regardless of whether entity A or entity C physically came up with them. That's what copyright means. That's the entire purpose of it. This does seem largely unfair but well that's what happens when you sign your IP rights away.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Plagiarism is orthogonal to ownership/copyright concerns. If you copy work that is under copyright and attribute it to its author, you have violated the copyright protection but not committed plagiarism. If you copy work and do not attribute it to its author, you have committed plagiarism irrespective or whether you have violated copyright protection or not.

Comment: @ff524: Okay.​​

Answer (score 6):

The plagiarism in any type would be discouraged and you can claim that plagiarism. The journal will investigate it and will find if it is plagiarism or not.
The theses is not the property of your supervisor as it's your effort and you may publish with or without your supervisor.

> IEEE Introduction to the Guidelines for Handling Plagiarism
>   Complaints. (n.d.). Retrieved September 22, 2014, from
>   http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/plagiarism.html

Comment: Those guidelines are for the editors of the journals ... so the proper procedure for someone who believes they've been plagarized would be to contact the editor of the journal that published the paper, and inform them of the apparent plagarism.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the whole story in detail, I would just say that if you contributed *significantly* to the work that has been published then you should be a co-author. If you are not, this may count as plagiarism (look at misleading attribution at [iThenticate](http://www.ithenticate.com/resources/reports/decoding-plagiarism-and-attribution)).

It would be wise, however, to contact them to subtly enquire about the issue before throwing any accusations. Throwing false accusations can be more harmful to your future career than losing credit for some work you did.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible explanations. It might be that they considered the algorithm to be easy to find and that they just didn't think of citing you.  On the other hand, if they were quite surprised by your algorithm, it's surprising that they would neglect to mention your contribution.

Either way, I would try asking them, in a friendly way.

Comment: Thank you. Will contact them. Whether the algorithm was pretty trivial or not is subjective. Moreover if they wrote a long section just on that algorithms, then probably it was not trivial.

Comment: Most likely they didn't think that much about the issue; they were just worried about getting another publication for a "checkmark". If you use the right strategy when contacting them, you should be successful. Just be wise. Talk to someone old for advice, perhaps to a woman.

Answer (score -1):

First off, your understanding of copyright is flawed.  The original author retains original copyright, and in your case, your university has, by virtue of being your university, been granted by you (look it up...it's in there) an unlimited LICENSE to use your copyright, and possibly/probably some first publication rights.

They do not own the copyright.

This is the same with patents.  You discover something?  You have the patent, which is assigned to the University.  Your name is still on it, even though they own the rights to it.

Now, on to attribution:  An unpublished work is generally not "citeable."  It adds no credence or credibility.  The appropriate structure here (assuming all the writeup at face value) is that you should receive an attribution as a contributor.  i.e. "implementation and algorithm concepts are based on the thesis work of gaganbm."  If your work was actually published in a journal or such, a citation would be very appropriate.

Comment: _An unpublished work is generally not "citeable."_ — This is simply false.  **Authors are required to give proper credit to prior work, whether or not that work is formally published.** People cite otherwise-unpublished master's (or even bachelor's theses all the time.  Of course it would be better for OP to make their thesis available, either as a technical report, or on the arXiv, or even just on their personal web site, so that readers of the citing paper can see the work.  But even this is not a requirement for citation.

Comment: In the case of work for hire (which is a legal mechanism by which a university may assert ownership of the copyright of a student employee's thesis) the employer (here, the university) is considered the author of the work for copyright purposes. So while it's *possible* that the student holds the copyright and licenses some rights to the university (as you suggest), if the student was funded, it's also possible that the university does, in fact, own the copyright.

Comment: Adding to @JeffE's comment, in a paper I wrote, I was told to cite 7 year old slides from a small conference I did not attend because they stated a theorem I proved. And this was not in a field in which giving a talk is equivalent to publishing. Actually, this very much irked me; I had never heard of the slides until the reviewer pointed them out to me, so it seemed *dishonest* to cite them. But I digress.

Comment: @JeffE, I agree.  One should always cite where outside work came from, even if it's unpublished.  My comment, which was admittedly slightly obtuse, mentions that citing unpublished work doesn't necessarily HELP you, because generally speaking, it's not available to review, should someone want to find it.

Answer (score -2):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but one thing I haven't heard mentioned in this discussion is the fact that, in many universities, accepted theses and dissertations are at least self-published by the university, and are made available in some form to the public.  This would make it citable even if it wasn't actually published in a journal.  This, I should think, would add weight to the claim of plagiarism.

Comment: A thesis is citable even if it isn't published. Virtually anything is citable, published or not. This doesn't seem like an answer to the question to me.

Comment: If have seen citations marked as (private communication). It's just about the honesty - make clear this wasn't your work, but someone else's.

Answer (score -3):

You need to check your university's policies on the faculty/student authorship question: your professor/s may have every right to use your work in this way, which used to be standard academic practice. Standard copyright/intellectual property rules may be waived or not applicable to your situation.

Comment: This is not an intellectual property issue. Publication ethics require that other people's ideas must be attributed properly, regardless of who owns these ideas. There is no university policy that exempts faculty from standard publication ethics.

Comment: Plagiarism is the *unattributed* use of ideas, whether or not there is copyright involved. Copyright infringement is the *unauthorized* publication of creative content, whether or not attribution is given. One can waive only the latter; plagiarism is an issue between the plagiarist and the community, and the original creator cannot give away some "right to be cited."

Answer (score -9):

What college did you go to? Your thesis was done at a University/College under the instruction of your School. They have a clause in all Universities in England which states that any ideas you come up with/Develop at University belongs to the university itself. This is how the vast majority of Uni's make money by selling patents.

Usually the University will publish ideas/sell patents with the student in partnership. However if its for a small publication (Which no money is received its for the good of the general public) then there is no need to notify the student.

Look up the clauses of your university faculty before making wild allegations of Plagiarism. Having done a Masters you should know to carry out research before coming to a conclusion

Kind Regards

Comment: This is false. Ownership of the intellectual property is a separate issue; publication ethics require attribution of others' ideas regardless of who "owns" them. There is no university clause that exempts its faculty from following standard publication ethics.

Comment: Seeing your comment I might have interpreted his question wrongly (Sorry about that). My major was Engineering therefore most ideas from Thesis are used in collaboration with the student who created them. I will still stress the easiest way to solve this is to talk to the faculty and ask them for the specific documentation about publication. Instead of allegations of plagiarism. Thanks

Comment: I h\ave come across the opposite more often than not, when IP is too small for the University to get involved with and lets the student/faculty member to do what they want

Comment: The situation as the OP has described it is **clearly** plagiarism.  This does not depend on "the clauses of...university faculty".  Your allegation that the OP would be making a wild allegation seems rather...wild.  "Having done a Masters you should know to carry out research before coming to a conclusion." Not only is this swipe at the OP completely gratuitous, it doesn't make much sense: the whole point is that the OP is trying to find out what is the right thing to do!  I would recommend that you delete your answer: it is not helpful.

Comment: As I [just explained](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28857/is-it-plagiarism-for-my-thesis-advisor-to-publish-a-paper-using-content-from-my#comment62533_28906) on another answer, the "right to be cited" is not transferable; plagiarism is a violation of the community's standards, *not* an individual's rights.