# Is it common for supervisors to approach their student and ask to work on publishing the student's masters thesis?

Tags: publications, thesis, masters, journals, advisor

My supervisor emailed me asking if he can work on trying to publish my masters thesis, with me being the first author. I have said yes, is it common for supervisors to approach students asking to publish students research?

Comment: I have to say it is refreshing to see a question about an advisor reaching out to a former advisee _prior_ to publishing thesis results rather than not at all (e.g., as highlighted [in this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28857/is-it-plagiarism-for-my-thesis-advisor-to-publish-a-paper-using-content-from-my)).

Answer (score 7):

There are in all likelihood differences between fields of study. In mine, it is uncommon, but if it happend it would be a good sign: You have produced something that is worth publishing, which is rare for a Master thesis in my field. Turning that research in an article that can be published is an art, which I would not expect a master student to master. So having the supervisor help you in that would be necessary in my field. It is right, that your supervisor immediately cleared who would be first author, and also right that you are the first author. That to me is a sign, that (s)he has the best intentions.

When I make such offers, I consider this as offering those students an opportunity to get an advantage very early in their (potential) academic career, or at least to get some inside experience of what working in academia is really like.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that in some field, it is expected to publish master thesis and the burden of it falls on the student.

Answer (score 1):

I would say depend on the personality and interests from the adviser. I have worked with adviser that loves to push a certain idea and anything that you worked on would help lead to a published paper that enhance this certain idea, he'll jump right on it and gives me plenty of journal contacts and help me publish it. I also have some that are not very helpful, and half-hearted but wants his name added to the paper without doing any work or helping in any way.

In your case, it looks like your adviser wants to help you and appreciate the quality of your work.