# Did my professor act unethically by publishing a paper with a figure from my thesis without any acknowledgement?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, ethics, authorship, acknowledgement

Title says it all, but for specifics..

Just found out my thesis advisor published a paper last year using a figure from my thesis. The thesis is in embargo until later this year.

I do have be honest and say that the figure in question is a redraft (with some slight alteration) from an older study. However, it is clear my advisor used the exact file from my thesis work. To his credit, he added a different section on the overall figure, but the part of my redraft is identical and was not altered in any way.

I was not part of the writing process, so it makes sense I'm not an author. However, I thought I'd at least be mentioned in the acknowledgements? Which brings up the bigger question of, are acknowledgements held to the same "ethical regard"? Can you just blatantly use someone's work without giving any credit at all if they didn't do enough to warrant authorship?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it plagiarism for my thesis advisor to publish a paper using content from my thesis without citation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28857/is-it-plagiarism-for-my-thesis-advisor-to-publish-a-paper-using-content-from-my)

Comment: What sort of embargo: purely academic because the thesis is so far unpublished, or embargoed because it contains a sponsor's proprietary material which has commercial or intelligence value?

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd purely academic

Answer (score 37):

There really aren't two ways around it: Yes, using someone else's figure is unethical.

The question of what to do about it is of course much harder to answer.

Comment: The asker did not inquire about what to do, but I think it is clear that nothing should be done.

Comment: Not only that, but even with an acknowledgment it would be unethical if the advisor did not ask for your consent to use your figure.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Actually, I didn't want to imply that nothing should be done. It's a much more difficult question because that involves human interactions.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. And yeah, not sure what to do from here. Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated! This isn't new behavior from him. He's also written a manuscript based on my actual thesis. He put me as third author and claimed I never took initiative to publish the results. Since I wasn't part of the main writing process and just edits/reviews (this is currently going on) he has said I will stay third author when I tried to fight it.

Comment: He what ? This is way out of line. See the HoD right now, man.

Comment: Speak to the head of department or whoever has been assigned to represent you.

Answer (score 5):

It’s a bit crass to do this and keep you out of the loop, but he did reorganize the figure so technically it is not “the figure from your thesis”, especially if it’s a redraft from and old study, *i.e.* not the final data used in “your figure”.

Even if the context is substantially different (i.e. different interpretation of the data), one would think that he would have let you know - especially if it is data you collected - but he didn’t.  The correct way for him to proceed would have been to let you know he was going to *adapt* or *insert* (as these terms seem to best describe what he had done) a figure from your thesis, and indicate as much in the text.

Not acknowledging someone is bad manners, not unethical.  If there is too much similarity between “his figure” and “your figure” (or more generally between your work and his work) and you are not a co-author, then it is plagiarism.  The threshold with figures is quite high and it’s not uncommon for people to redraw old, already published, figure and change minor details (sometimes only the font) so they are not technically re-using copyrighted material.

Comment: You miss the point that, in some fields, figures/graphs/etc can have an instant impact on the reader, can say in a second what loads of text painfully aggregates. This is especially so in showing an anomaly to a previously presumed trend. By using the OP's - as yet unpublished - adapted figure (which in itself may include additional interesting data and/or perspectives) as well as his own changes, he may be to some extent pre-publishing and credit stealing, in my view. This is unacceptable in an academic environment where a relationship of trust must exist between colleagues.

Comment: @Trunk I don’t disagree and I would never do this myself but people do and they argue they rejigged the figures to avoid technical plagiarism.   Again I think it’s particularly insensitive to do this to your student, but simply because it’s stupid doesn’t mean it’s unethical or illegal.

Comment: @Trunk Clearly here by using the same figure template with an old data set rather than the most recent data, the goal is (at least in my mind) to avoid technical plagiarism, and it *will* lessen the impact of the thesis once the embargo has ended

Comment: Any professor with a shred of decency would not seek to publish *anything* related to his student's work till the student had first published the primary paper - a paper in which the professor presumably would be a co-author anyhow. By getting a sole author paper out ahead of his student's paper he is making the student's work look like that of a frontman rather than that of an independent researcher.

Comment: If you use or modify another person's nontrivial work (the question author stated it was clearly from the specific file they had) without permission or acknowledgement, then it is plagiarism. The similarity of the end result is not the only consideration.

Comment: @Trunk Absolutely!

Comment: @Era it’s not so clear.  Here (as I understand), a *similar* figure using different data but the same template was used, thereby NOT modifying the student original work, but independently producing instead alook-alike.   I still think it lacks decency (to use wording of another comment) and in very poor judgement.

Comment: Wrote the following on a different comment, but think it's useful on this discussion too to clear any doubts. Half of the published figure is definitely the figure from my thesis (he has the files, as he asked for them at the end of my time there). Also, to explain further, think of the figure my advisor published as two halves. The bottom half is the exact redrafted figure on my thesis. The top half is a sorta "blown-up," more detailed look at the process that the bottom half is alluding to (albeit, with my advisor's slightly own take on it).

Comment: @rowrow what’s the deal with the “older study” then?

Comment: Depending on your location, even if you make minor alterations, it would still count as plagiarism and potentially copyright infringement if you do not cite the original source. @ZeroTheHero The figure _in the thesis_ is a redraft of a figure from an older study. The figure in the professor’s text comprises a direct copy of the figure from the thesis plus an extra expounding section added by the professor.

Answer (score -2):

Briefly:

If your thesis results had already been published beforehand, your professor should have acknowledged both the original author *and you* in relation to using this figure. At least a footnote close to the figure referencing the original author's paper and your own paper, if not a more explicit mention in the *Results* section.

But that isn't what really bothering you here, is it ?

**What is - understandably - bugging you is that someone took a small but original part of your upcoming thesis results and presentation then published them ahead of you, the original author.**

The professor stole a part of your thunder.

I really get where you are coming from both professionally and emotionally.
This is not a mere lack of authoring etiquette that can be apologized away. It is a sneaky (he didn't talk to you about this, let alone ask your permission) attempt to hijack the novel and impressive side of **your effort**.

I really feel for you in this and I think you should discuss this with the Head of Department. It may well result in a situation leaves you with the task of explaining what is "new knowledge" in your own work since an extension of one of your important figures has been previously published.

How one professor behaves in this regard can have an effect on the behaviour of other faculty. If this type of hijack is uncommented on, no researcher will feel safe in working hard towards their ultimate goal of being the first to put in the results of their years of research and getting most of the credit for everything the extracted from it.

Answer (score -3):

The legality and morality really all depend on circumstances, i.e. on how much work was put into the redraft, is the outcome clearly different, or was your figure a "quote" of the figure in the earlier study. Also, who wrote the earlier study?

Here is a scenario. Your prof or their group writes a study with the figure and looses the original pdf file. You publish this study figure in your thesis by reconstructing it, maybe under guidance of your prof. Your figure and the study figure are difficult to tell apart. Your prof or someone else when writing the paper look for the study figure and finds your version. Nothing wrong in my opinion for using it legally (they still have the copyright to derivatives of their original work) and ethically (they were not able to tell that you contributed to the figure).

Here is another scenario. You truly embellish the figure from the earlier study so that it has changed character and you now hold copyright for your substantial changes, as maybe the only intellectual contribution of the original figure are the data. The prof or the person who wrote the section likes your version, is afraid that you would not want to give permission for use, does not know how to cite an embargoed thesis, forgets to ask you, or just assumes that you are fine with it. Then your rights were violated. Even then, what can you gain by asserting your rights? There is not much you can claim. You cannot become a co-author because your contribution is too low and the paper has already been published. You did not suffer any material damage. You benefitted from the work in the group (you got a thesis accepted so you got a degree, I assume) and some give and take in a group is expected. You might have been owned an acknowledgment: "We thank rowrow for taking the figure from X and colleagues [x] and redrawing it." I could live without that.

To long to read: Assert the facts first, e.g. was it intentional, and was your "redraft" different enough. Even if this would have been bad, you missed out on a small note of thanks. These are pretty worthless in academia and completely worthless in industry.

Comment: You're only addressing copyright, but the most blatant offense here is plagiarism.

Comment: Using a redrawn figure from the group is not plagiarism. The work is in getting the data, not putting them into a figure. There are exceptions for explanatory figures, but the OP does not claim that. Research is not undergraduate studies and different rules apply.

Comment: Different rules than what? I don't understand your comment about undergraduate studies. The OP is talking about their thesis advisor, not about an undergraduate student. Reusing a figure from someone else's paper and claiming it's your own is plagiarism. It's as simple as that. I don't know what "rules" you're referring to.

Comment: @Stef … but the thesis director is *not* using the figure as he has reproduced it using different data.  I still think the thesis director showed very poor judgement here, even if he may be technically right.  Showing different data using a same template as another publication is not plagiarism.  It still in bad taste to do this to your student though, especially if the thesis is embargoed.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Apparently you and I understand the OP's words in two very different ways.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. To clear it up, the old study was not from our research group. It was an old study from the 80s not many people had paid attention to. I found their interpretation very interesting and agreed with parts of it, hence the redraft (with slight alteration) on my thesis.

Comment: Also, to explain further, think of the figure my advisor published as two halves. The bottom half is the exact redrafted figure on my thesis. The top half is a sorta "blown-up," more detailed look at the process that the bottom half is alluding to (albeit, with my advisor's slightly own take on it).